# How to redirect old links to new SEO friendly links?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I just started developing web sites. I know that this question has been asked many times. Although, I checked most of them, I could not manage to redirect old links to new SEO friendly links.
mysite.com/search.php?word=thanks and mysite.com/thanks boths works. When form is submtited, site runs the old link. I have been trying to solve this problem and searching web for hours. I have added this code at the bottom of the .htdocs file but didn't work.

```
RewriteRule search.php?word=^(.*)$ $1 [R=301,L]
```

Here is my .htdocs codes

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^WebWhacker [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^WebZIP [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Wget [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Widow [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^WWWOFFLE [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Xaldon\ WebSpider [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Zeus
RewriteRule .* - [F]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ search.php?word=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a new redirect rule:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^WebWhacker [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^WebZIP [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Wget [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Widow [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^WWWOFFLE [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Xaldon\ WebSpider [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Zeus
RewriteRule .* - [F]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /search\.php\?word=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1? [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ search.php?word=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: This solved my problem. Thank you so much. @anubhava

Comment: Hello, I'd like to redirect dizisozluk.net/words to dizisozluk.net/ne-demek/anlami/words and change plus (+) sign to dash (-) sign. For example dizisozluk.net/family+tree to dizisozluk.net/ne-demek/anlami/family-tree .
Could you please help to change this?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: @FatihYavuz: Please post a new question for that requirement and we'll help you out.